# How can you tell if a solana node is synced?

Tags: solana

I'm running a solana node using the `solana-validator` command (see [Solana docs](https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start#connect-your-validator)).

And I'd like to know if my validator is ready to connect to the http/rpc/ws port. What's the quickest way to do check to see if it's synced?

Currently, I'm using [`wscat`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat) to check to see if I can connect to the websocket, but am unable to. I'm not sure if that's because the node isn't setup right, or it's not synced, etc.

I know if I run `solana gossip` I should be able to see my IP in the list that populates... but is that the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a `curl` command against your node for block height:

```
curl http://<IP>:<PORT> -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"getBlockHeight"}'
```

And you'll get an output like:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":105334870,"id":1}
```

Compare this to some other node, like a [block explorer](https://explorer.solana.com/), and see if you're up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `solana catchup`, which does exactly what you're asking for: https://docs.solana.com/cli/usage#solana-catchup

Comment: Does that come standard? It says command not found.

Comment: I don't know when it was added, but it's present in 1.8.1, which is the oldest release that I have cached on my machine at the moment.  The newest version is currently 1.9.3, so be sure to update using `solana-install init 1.9.3`